# Highlight words in particular class using JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, highlight, cpu-word

Given div's of a particular class, I want to highlight words that exist in in a JS array containing keywords.

**For example:**

```
  var cars = ["hello", "when", "why"];
  <p class="highlighted">How are you when</p>
  <p>How are you</p>
```

Comment: I have tried but it highlights the words on complete page but i want only on particular class

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried but it highlights the words on complete page but i want
>   only on particular class

Use `document.getElementsByClassName("highlighed")`, this will return a htmlcollection which have only this specific class

This below snippet may be useful.Have added comments for description

```js
var cars = ["hello", "when", "why", "are"];
//get the dom which have this specific class
var classes = document.getElementsByClassName("highlighed");
//convert collection to array to use array method
//forEach is array method
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("highlighed")).forEach(function(item) {
  //get the innerHTML and remove whitespace and create an array from it
  var getText = item.innerHTML.trim().split(' ');
  // iterate this newly created array
  getText.forEach(function(item2, index) {
    //check if any text is matching with cars array
    if (cars.indexOf(item2) > -1) {
      // replace the element in newly created array with dom element
      getText[index] = "<span class='lightText'>" + item2 + "</span>"
    }
  });
  // create string array using join
  item.innerHTML = getText.join(' ');
})
```

```css
.lightText {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="highlighed">How are you when</p>
<p>How are you</p>
```